# How can I solve "Can't assign requested address" when trying to receive UDP broadcast?

Tags: python, udp, ip-address

I have a device that broadcasts UDP packets to `255.255.255.255` and I want to receive this using Python.  What's wrong with the below code?

```py
import socket
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
server.bind(('255.255.255.255', 10002))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address
```

If I use `<broadcast>` instead, it throws the same exception.  If I use a different IP like `192.168.4.255` then it works, but then I can't receive data sent to `255.255.255.255`.

This code actually works fine on Ubuntu.  But the problem happens on two different macOS machines.

Comment: You should be able to bind to your own machine's IP address.  Because the sender is using a broadcast address, it should be received by ALL network devices on the subnet.

Comment: You don't bind to the broadcast address. You should bind to INADDR_ANY actually.